# How to replace the stock camera app on Android?

Tags: applications, camera

I installed a GSI ROM on my Lenovo Legion Y700 tablet. This software comes with a camera app that I don't like. It is called `org.lineageos.aperture`. I found a Gcam app that works fine on my tablet.

Is there any (even dangerous) way to replace the stock camera app with Gcam?

I do not know English, so I used a translator, I apologize if my text is not quite correct, I hope you will understand what I want.

Comment: Standard Androids allow installation of standard canera apps. The stock one stays ther but doesnt has to be used.  Cant you just install one?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like you're using LineageOS? As far as I know, [OpenGapps](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Package-Comparison) allows replacing the stock camera with Gcam. However, both [LineageOS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/heart/install#installing-add-ons) and [OpenGapps](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ#7-i-read-that-google-camera-can-only-be-installed-during-a-clean-install-or-as-an-update-to-an-existing-open-gapps-installation-what-does-this-mean) recommended to flash the package before the first boot.

Comment: Apart from that, you'll need root access to manually modify system files & apps, which is more prone to error.

Comment: Do you really need to **replace** Aperture – or do you simply want to use a different camera app? You could just install another one, then disable Aperture in *Settings › Apps.* That way, no rooting and no danger to "break things". GCam might be a special case here as it requires (parts of) Google Services. That can be worked around using e.g. [Gcam Services Provider](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.lukaspieper.gcam.services/) from F-Droid or its [advanced version](https://apt.izzysoft.de/packages/com.google.android.apps.photos/) with support for Google Photos, from my repo.